# MonetDB storage() function

Tags: monetdb

From MonetDB docs 
https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Cookbooks/SQLrecipes/storage-model,

```
The storage footprint for any given database schema
can be obtained by inspecting the table producing 
function storage()
```

Here's a sample query from the documentation:

```
select * from storage() where "table" = 'lineitem';
```

But when I try a similar query,  I get below error:

```
SELECT: no such operator 'storage'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefixing the storage() function call with the "sys" schema may solve your issue. Ex :

`select * from sys.storage() where "table" = 'lineitem';`